# What is wrong with my js code . The result is always undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just started learning javascript and i was trying to create like a calculator just to add,sub,multiply and divide two numbers. But the result is always undefined. Can you please tell me where the problem is?

```
    //Two functions
    function output() {

     var input1 = document.getElementById("nr1").value;
     var input2 = document.getElementById("nr2").value;
     var result = document.getElementById("result");

      result.innerHTML = calculate(input1, input2).value;
     }

     function calculate(input1, input2) {

       var add = document.getElementById("add");
       var sub = document.getElementById("sub");
       var mul = document.getElementById("mul");
       var div = document.getElementById("div");
       var rez
       //How to know when we click one button?

       if (add == true) {
          rez = parseFloat(input1 + input2);
          return rez;
       } else if (sub == true) {
          rez = parseFloat(input1 - input2);
          return rez;
       } else if (mul == true) {
          rez = parseFloat(input1 * input2);
          return rez;
       } else if (div == true) {
          rez = parseFloat(input1 / input2);
          return rez;
       } else {
          return 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: When do these functions run? What is the value of `input1` and `input2` at that time?

Comment: Hard to tell without your html

Comment: `add`, `sub`  etc are elements. Why are comparing them with `true`?

Comment: You're comparing DOM elements with `true`, which will never be true. In your code you have a question: *"How to know when we click one button?"* You know by setting up a click handler on each individual button. That is, instead of one handler that tries to figure out which button was clicked, you have individual handlers that handle clicks from their specific button.

Comment: While all the above comments correctly point out issues within the function, none address why `undefined` is being returned. Even with the problems with the `if` statement, `0` should at least be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`calculate` is a function that you have returning a number. Numbers don't have a `value` property. All you want is the returned value from within the function so:

Change:

```
result.innerHTML = calculate(input1, input2).value;
```

To:

```
result.innerHTML = calculate(input1, input2);
```

And, as others have pointed out in the comments, your `if` statement is trying to compare elements in your page with `true`.

Instead, you should be checking what the element contains. If it is a form-field (input, select, textarea, etc.), check the element's `.value` property. If not, check its `.textContent` property. Now, based on your use case, you need to know which button was clicked so that you can do the correct math operation. For that, you'd work with the `click` events and perform the correct operation. See the following along with the comments for a possible solution:

```js
// Get references to the elements you'll work with
let input1 = document.getElementById("one");
let input2 = document.getElementById("two");
let result = document.getElementById("result");

// Set up a click event hanlder at the document level
document.addEventListener("click", calculate);

function calculate(event) {
  // First, check to see if the event originated at one of the math buttons
  if(event.target.classList.contains("operator")){
    // One of the operator buttons was clicked.
    // Get the textContent of that button and do the appropriate math
    let operation = event.target.textContent;
    
    if(operation === "+"){
      // The prepended + sign converts the string value to a number
      result.textContent = +input1.value + +input2.value;
    } else if(operation === "-") {
      result.textContent =  +input1.value - +input2.value;
    } else if(operation === "*") {
      result.textContent =  +input1.value * +input2.value;
    } else {
      result.textContent =  +input1.value / +input2.value;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="one"><br>
<input id="two">
<button type="button" class="operator">+</button>
<button type="button" class="operator">-</button>
<button type="button" class="operator">*</button>
<button type="button" class="operator">/</button>
<br>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ok, good point. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

why are you doing .value in calculate(input1, input2).value ?
since you are not returning an object, but a numeric value so you dont need to do .value

use onclick functionality to add click events